# Retrieve the names of photos albums (ALAssetsGroup) in Photos.app crash

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I'm trying to get all the albums names. here is what I do.

The method `[group valueForKey:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]` crashes

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos | ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                             usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

                                 if (nil != group)
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"name %@",[group valueForKey:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);    
                                 }
                                 *stop = NO;
                             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                             }];
```

I really don't know why it crashes, if someone knows, I'll really appreciate some help !

Here is the crash log :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ALAssetsGroup 0x17801ff90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ALAssetsGroupPropertyName.`
```

Comment: What are the details of the crash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling the wrong method. Change this:

```
NSLog(@"name %@",[group valueForKey:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);
```

to:

```
NSLog(@"name %@",[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks !! I'm soo stuupid !!